# Features of Docker Kubernetes Service (DKS)

Tags: docker, kubernetes

On [DockerCon 2019](https://www.docker.com/dockercon/) Docker announced the Docker Kubernetes Service (DKS).

Quoted from [here](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3391214/docker-enterprise-30-integrates-secure-kubernetes-stack.html):

> Docker Enterprise 3.0’s Docker Kubernetes Service (DKS) integrates
>   Kubernetes container orchestration from the developer desktop to the
>   production server.
>
> ...It also provides an automated way to install and configure
>   Kubernetes applications across hybrid and multi-cloud deployments.
>   Other capabilities include security, access control, and lifecycle
>   management

And from [here](https://www.docker.com/products/kubernetes):

> The Docker platform includes a secure and fully-conformant Kubernetes
>   environment for developers and operators of all skill levels,
>   providing out-of-the-box integrations for common enterprise
>   requirements while still enabling complete flexibility for expert
>   users.

After some searching and research I haven't succeed to fully understand the different solutions and features that DKS has to offer. So, my question is: 
**What DKS has to offer regarding topics like: Security, Networking, Access Management, etc'**?

I'll start with what I discovered so far as an entry point for the discussion, hopefully that others will share there own understanding and experience and maybe provide some references and examples.

Answer (score 1):

This is very basic - but I'll share what I found so far - starting with the [product page](https://www.docker.com/products/kubernetes) as my entry point for research.

**Security**

1. Secure Kubernetes cluster with [TLS authentication and encryption](https://docs.docker.com/compliance/nist/fips140_2/).
2. Integrated security for the application lifecycle with [Docker Content Trust](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/trust/content_trust/).
3. Integration with [validated and certified 3rd party tools](https://hub.docker.com/search/?q=&type=image&certification_status=certified)  (monitoring, logging, storage, 
   networking, etc') .

**Access control**

1. Restricting visibility for different user groups and operate multi-tenant environments - I found only this: [restrict services to worker nodes](https://docs.docker.com/ee/ucp/admin/configure/restrict-services-to-worker-nodes/#kubernetes-workloads).
2. Advanced Access Controls Docker Enterprise includes integrated RBAC that works with corporate LDAP, Active Directory, PKI certificates and/or SAML 2.0 identity provider solutions - I found only this: [Configure native Kubernetes role-based access control](https://docs.docker.com/ee/ucp/admin/configure/configure-rbac-kube/).

**Networking**

Found only [this](https://docs.docker.com/ee/ucp/kubernetes/install-cni-plugin/) which is related to installation of cni plugins. 
I think DKS offers much more regarding to integrating with 3rd party networking solutions  - Quoted from the product page:

> Out-of-the-box Networking Docker Enterprise includes Project Calico by
>   Tigera as the “batteries included” Kubernetes CNI plug-in for a highly
>   scalable, networking and routing solution. Get access to overlay
>   (IPIP), no overlay, and hybrid data-plane networking models in
>   addition to native Kubernetes ingress controllers for load balancing.